# Вывести индексы тех элементов, значения которых больше значения предыдущего элемента

Tags: java

Возник такой вопрос. Как вывести индексы элементов, значения которых больше значения предыдущего элемента(начиная со второго). На голову приходит только данное решение этой задачи, но данная программа не сравнивает последний элемент с предпоследним, не могу понять в чем дело. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a; // массив целых чисел
        int n; // количество элементов в массиве
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите количество эл-ов");
        n = in.nextInt();
        a = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) (-20 + (Math.random() * (40 + 20)));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + a[i]);
        }
        /* интересуемая часть */
        int y = n;
        for (int i = 1; i < y - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i + 1] > a[i])
                System.out.print((i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если со второго, то все верно, цикл с 1. Но судя по описанию вывести надо те, которые по значению больше предыдущего. Так что попробуйте вот так:

```
/* интересуемая часть */
for (int i = 1; i < n ; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i - 1]) {
        System.out.print((i) + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, данное решение мне помогло!

Comment: не за что. Успехов